# Twilio How to collect incoming SMS messages using .net efficiently

Tags: vb.net, sms, twilio

I created an application in VB.net that ties into a scheduling software. It keeps our employees up to date by sending them SMS updates. Employees can reply back to us. Sending messages works great. The application uses the Rest API to connect to Twilio. I can also get a list of incoming messages but I can't seem to get it in a way that works well for me.

Currently my application checks if there are new messages every 5 minutes. The application gets the messages list (with filter DateSent>=today) and then loops through the messages and copies the new ones into our scheduling database.

Is it possible to do a more efficient data pull for new SMS messages using VB.net only? Can I include a time filter in addition to current filter DateSent>=today to limit the result set? Any suggestions? (I don't do web coding unfortunately) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

The best way to do this is just to use Twilios web hook to let Twilio proactively tell you each time its received a message.  Whats a web hook you ask?  Great question.

A webhook is simply an HTTP request that Twilio will make as soon as it received an inbound SMS messages to your Twilio phone number.  You normally tell Twilio to make this HTTP request to a URL that you've created and published to a public website, which you can set up easily by using something like ASP.NET.  In this scenario you can think of Twilio like a web browser that is making a request to a web application that you have created.

You can tell Twilio what URL it should request by opening the **Numbers** tab in your Twilio dashboard, and then locating and clicking the phone number you want to configure:

[image]

Now you set the URL you want Twilio to request in the Message Request URL field and click Save:

[image]

Now when Twilio requests this URL its going to pass a [bunch of parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) with its request that you can use in your application logic.  You can also do things like return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) back to Twilio in response to its HTTP request that tell it to do things like [send an SMS right back to the person who just sent one to you](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/replying-to-sms-messages).

If you're looking for a bit more of a step by step, the [Quickstarts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms) on our website are pretty easy to follow and will walk you through both sending an receiving text messages.  The samples are in C# but are pretty straight forward so converting to VB.NET should be easy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Twilio Evangelist,  Do you know when they do the post they also send the encrypted X-Twilio-Signature" header in the request to the url Request URL

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar with VB.Net and Twilio. My solution was to put up an Azure web site and an Azure SQL Database (the two can talk to each other).  I set up my Twlio to call an .ashx asp.net web page on my Azure web site.  Inside of that web page I have code that reads the incoming text message and saves it to my Azure SQL Database.

Works great, but my problem is the Azure database is in "the cloud" and my app\database that sends the original SMS is on mylocal network. Not sure how to cross that divide... (I should add that my local app can read the Azure SQL database, but seems ugly to have to call out to the Azure to get data. Would have preferred to have just saved it in my local db to begin with.)

Probably not a very helpful post, but maybe give you some architectural ideas. If you want to see my .ashx page just let me know.